# How to save 0 as the first number in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which stores only 6 digit numbers and there are numbers which contain 0 as there first letter even there are numbers which contain more than one 0's as there first letters..

```
          using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
            {

                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@numType", numTyp));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@numFrom", textBox1.Text));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@numTo", textBox2.Text));
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }

                scope.Complete();
```

data is being saved and also retrieving but if the first numbers are 0's then sql omits them,, they are important... for eg a number 001234 is saved as 1234 in db .. so how can i fix this i searched but no luck ..

using Sqlserver 2008 visualstudio 2010 c#

hope it is not vague,, Thanks in Advance

**EDIT: I am using int as a data type**

Comment: I ran into similar problem, what we did was to store it in another field as string type

Answer (score 4):

This is a datatype issue: If you use `int`, the numerical value will be stored, so 001234 will be stored as the number 1234.

You can recreate the zero-padding later, but it is not part of the stored data: `0001234` is the same **integer number** as `01234` or `1234`.

- If you want to left-pad all numbers to a certain length, use `String.Format()` after retrieval.
- If `0001234` and `1234` are different values, use a string-like data type

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The problem isn't with the retrieving, it's that data are stored in int columns as just integers, without the string formating.

Use another data type if you want your database to store the number of 0 before your int, either a string, a couple of ints with one of them being the number of zeros, or another format more suitable to your precise needs.

EDIT : if your zeros aren't significative (they're just to complement), keep your format as an int and just add as many "0" at the beginning as you want.

Comment: Exactly. THis is not a number, it is a 5 character string that only allows numbers by pattern. It should not be a in data type to start with.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the bias against storing as an int and formatting on display? That seems like a really reasonable thing to do.

Comment: @BenThul : I just reread and I think now that those zeros aren't significative. I had missed the "all 6 digits" before.

Answer (score -2):

after asking and reviewing other answer,, i remembered a lesson thought in high school which states that int stores 235 characters but in reality it stores 234 characters, so i always wonder that the last letter might not be stored, but now in practical it is clear that it doesn't stores the very first letter 0 lol, i changed the data type to nvarchar(50) it stores retrieve both with 0 characters no matter how much ;)

Comment: Just FYI, this should be a comment or an edit to your question - it's not an answer. Glad you solved your issue though!

Comment: thanks for your comment but this part is my ans.. i changed the data type to nvarchar(50) it stores retrieve both with 0 characters no matter how much ;).... but i will takecare next time :)